# SQL server administrators group

Tags: sql-server

I have a service that runs under as specific windows user. 
That user is part of the adminstrators group.

In the SQL server database, I can see in the security pane : Builtin\Adminstrators.

The connections string contains Integrated Security = SSPI (no username or password).

Is the fact that I can connect to the database a result of my user being in the administrators group which corresponds to Builtin\Adminstrators in sql server?

JD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, yes it is.

SQL Server uses Windows Authentication (you can enable native SQL logins, as well, though), and that includes groups. If you add a group and give that group permissions (in this case, Builtin\Administrators), then every member of that group has access.

In SQL Server 2000 and 2005, Builtin\Administrators were default server administrators. In 2008, that's no longer the case, but many people go that route out of habit, anyway.

Comment: Cheers Eric. I had another developer shoot me down for even considering it. He insisted I need to have the user mapped in sql server.

Comment: @JD: Don't talk to developers about SQL Server security. Talk to DBAs. Just be careful when you do--you may end up losing an afternoon with that conversation.

Comment: @Eric: Will do, I need to post another question, so I might as well ask now (as I am on the train) : What is the difference between Integrated Security = True and Integrated Security = SSPI. I have two apps and each one works only with one of the strings each.

Comment: @JD: Best to post it as another question. I only know of `Trusted_Connection = True` and `Integrated Security = SSPI` as syntax differences, so there may be somebody that can provide a much more in depth answer for you.